# What is the best design to run the same task in different tomcat cluster nodes?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have different instances of tomcat in my system. Another system shall launch the same task (task to set webapp offline/online) in all the tomcat instances and must be notified of the result of the tasks. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy the Tomcat manager application in each clustered server and use that to control them. The manager provides a simple web based API for controlling a server instance. From your controlling server, issue HTTP calls to perform tasks in your controlled servers. The response data from the HTTP call will indicate wether the task succeeded or not.

Here is an example of making a call from your controlling server, using Apache's HTTP components library:

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com:8080/manager/stop?path=/myapp");
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
```

Note that when using the Tomcat manager you should always secure it with a username/password and protect it with SSL.

[Tomcat 6 - Manager Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html)